# Google Contact API V3 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-contacts-api

I am authenticating using OAuth2. Using an access token I can successfully access Calendar Lists via a Get, Calendar Events via a Post, and create a Calendar Event via a post.  Every attempt to do a Get to get a Contact List fails with a 403 Forbidden.

I authenticated with the following scope
scope=openid%20email%20https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar%20https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/

And during the login, see access to contacts listed.

My Get URL is https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?v=3.0

I have tried it with and without the v=3.0, and with my email address in place of default.

On the Google Developers console, I have Calendar API and Contact API enabled.

I had no trouble accessing the Contacts via the now deprecated V2 .net api, but using REST for V3 it just will not connect.  Unfortunately, unlike the Calendar API, there is no "tester" at the bottom of the Google page to send an OAuth2 request to retrieve a list of contacts.

Has anyone gotten this to work, or is there something simple I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

With Your request https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full
pass &key={{**your__access_token**}}.This should solve your problem.